# Fade Effect on Link Hover?

Tags: css, hover, fade, effect

on many sites, such as http://www.clearleft.com, you'll notice that when the links are hovered over, they will fade into a different color as opposed to immediately switching, the default action.

I assume JavaScript is used to create this effect, does anyone know how?

Comment: Thank you. Now, I understand how to make hover links, it's just that I'm trying to figure out how to create a smoother effect for my hover links.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Nowadays people are just using [CSS3 transitions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/css-fundamentals-css3-transitions--pre-10922) because it's a lot easier than [messing with JS](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color), browser support is reasonably good and it's merely cosmetic so it doesn't matter if it doesn't work.

Something like this gets the job done:

```css
a {
  color:blue;
  /* First we need to help some browsers along for this to work.
     Just because a vendor prefix is there, doesn't mean it will
     work in a browser made by that vendor either, it's just for
     future-proofing purposes I guess. */
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:.5s;
}
a:hover { color:red; }
```

You can also transition specific CSS properties with different timings and easing functions by separating each declaration with a comma, like so:

```css
a {
  color:blue; background:white;
  -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
  /* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
  transition:color .2s ease-out, background 1s ease-in;
}
a:hover { color:red; background:yellow; }
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/xejsM/52/)

Comment: @AndreiCristof: Luckily [works in IE10 though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673535(v=vs.85).aspx)! No vendor prefix required either (which is weird).

Comment: I tested both and i hope if i found correct reason that CSS way is not smooth and fluent as jQuery way. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: You rock!  Well explained, helped me out a lot by seeing it.

Comment: My test is with an image, not a link.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli best to post a question I guess, definitely sounds like a syntax problem.

Answer (score 9):

I know in the question you state "I assume JavaScript is used to create this effect" but CSS can be used too, an example is below.

**CSS**

```
.fancy-link {
   color: #333333;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: color 0.3s linear;
   -webkit-transition: color 0.3s linear;
   -moz-transition: color 0.3s linear;
}

.fancy-link:hover {
   color: #F44336;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="fancy-link" href="#">My Link</a>
```

And here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/nhd2yrm0/) for the above code!

---

Marcel in one of the answers points out you can "transition multiple CSS properties" you can also use "all" to effect the element with all your :hover styles like below.

**CSS**

```
.fancy-link {
   color: #333333;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.fancy-link:hover {
   color: #F44336;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="fancy-link" href="#">My Link</a>
```

And here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hec32of6/) for the "all" example!

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with JQueryUI:

```
$('a').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    color: '#ff0000'
  }, 1000);
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    color: '#000000'
  }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dWCbk/

Comment: you dont need jqueryui for that, just jquery

Comment: @Juan No, jQuery can only animate "single numeric values" which colors are not (see https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties). But you actually don't need the entire jQueryUI library, just the jQuery.Color plugin, that happens to be embedded into jQueryUI.

Comment: @Niclas Sahlin. I found your fiddle searching for CSS transitions. Your JQuery-UI transition is so much smoother, I'm sure the users will notice it.

Comment: There are solutions with css, which is way easier to implement

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your css:

```
.a {
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.a {
    color:turquoise;
}
.a:hover {
    color: #454545;
}
```