# how to animate color of a link on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i've few types of links on my website.

First is just simple link without any styles such as backgrounds.
The second type of links are with background colors similar to buttons.

these both have hover color change effect which is accomplished by CSS.

what i want is to animate that color change on hover, i want it to change smoothly.

is there any way to white a few line of code in master page of all other pages, so ever single link will animate its color change on hover?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008324/fade-effect-on-link-hover - the accepted answer shows how to achieve this with CSS transitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use CSS3 transitions on the `background-color` property.

For example:

```
a {
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Note that this won't work in all browsers (e.g. IE8).

For more examples see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: k. that worked for a link that doesn't have a background style. just fine for animating text color. how to do the same with background of a link? thanks.

Comment: ohhh.... sorry. just got it. replace "color" with "background-color". that is it :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with jQuery (via [3rd party plugins](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) that exist), OR [css3 transitions](http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/).

[Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKXWg/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKXWg/)

#### HTML

```
<a href="#">Hover me</a>
```

#### CSS

```
a,
a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: color ease-in-out 800ms;
    color: red;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

I've only included the `-webkit` vendor prefix, but applicable prefixes should be added/used.

Comment: **Most** important to include is the **`transition`** style, not specifically the vendor prefix ones

Answer (score 0):

Try using css3 transition property.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XjEC9/

```
a { 
   background-color: blue; 
   color: white; 
   transition-property: background-color, color; 
   transition-duration: 2s; 
   transition-timing-function: ease; 
}

a:hover { color: red; background-color: green; }
```