# How to add a hover border in a page in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I got an image, and I want to add a border when I hover the mouse. If it has a fadein animation even better.

But I have no idea how to link a class to my image. where should I define it?. And if I update the Wordpress version, it is deleted?.

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/Xv6La/274/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking quite a few question in this *one* issue.

Your first question is how you create a `class` in CSS. You can [read about that here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).

The next *'question'* is about fading (well, you more alluded to the idea of wanting a `transition`) - you can [read about *that* here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008324/fade-effect-on-link-hover) or [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Your last question is about updating Wordpress; will it affect your custom `css`. That is completely dependent on how you went about adding the custom `css`. If the theme gets updated, it might override your changes, if you used some sort of theme customizer, backend custom css module; that *also* might get overridden, but it is *completely dependent* on how you go about adding your custom css.

Sorry I didn't get into specifics, that's because I am unsure about your current code.